# G1 young gc suddenly took more time to complete

Tags: java, garbage-collection, g1gc

PFB logs. Young gc which took place at 2019-01-29T22:26:37.545+0000: took only 0.03 seconds. Where as young gc at 2019-01-29T22:27:04.257+0000 just after 30 sec or so took 1.87 seconds. Amount of memory collected is almost same in two gcs. I am unable to understand what would cause it?

I have checked CPU load was 20% on the server.

If cpu is free it should have finished it in normal time.

Logs from application:

```
2019-01-29T22:26:37.545+0000: [GC pause (G1 Evacuation Pause) (young)
Desired survivor size 19922944 bytes, new threshold 15 (max 15)
- age   1:    2916480 bytes,    2916480 total
 39329.271: [G1Ergonomics (CSet Construction) start choosing CSet, _pending_cards: 1469, predicted base time: 14.84 ms, remaining time: 185.16 ms, target pause time: 200.00 ms]
 39329.271: [G1Ergonomics (CSet Construction) add young regions to CSet, eden: 144 regions, survivors: 3 regions, predicted young region time: 92.66 ms]
 39329.271: [G1Ergonomics (CSet Construction) finish choosing CSet, eden: 144 regions, survivors: 3 regions, old: 0 regions, predicted pause time: 107.50 ms, target pause time: 200.00 ms]
, 0.0309821 secs]
   [Parallel Time: 27.7 ms, GC Workers: 4]
      [GC Worker Start (ms): Min: 39329271.8, Avg: 39329271.9, Max: 39329272.0, Diff: 0.3]
      [Ext Root Scanning (ms): Min: 6.4, Avg: 7.2, Max: 8.9, Diff: 2.4, Sum: 28.7]
      [Update RS (ms): Min: 0.0, Avg: 3.1, Max: 9.4, Diff: 9.4, Sum: 12.4]
         [Processed Buffers: Min: 0, Avg: 10.0, Max: 24, Diff: 24, Sum: 40]
      [Scan RS (ms): Min: 0.0, Avg: 0.1, Max: 0.2, Diff: 0.2, Sum: 0.4]
      [Code Root Scanning (ms): Min: 0.0, Avg: 0.0, Max: 0.0, Diff: 0.0, Sum: 0.0]
      [Object Copy (ms): Min: 11.4, Avg: 16.8, Max: 19.1, Diff: 7.7, Sum: 67.4]
      [Termination (ms): Min: 0.0, Avg: 0.1, Max: 0.1, Diff: 0.1, Sum: 0.3]
      [GC Worker Other (ms): Min: 0.1, Avg: 0.1, Max: 0.1, Diff: 0.1, Sum: 0.3]
      [GC Worker Total (ms): Min: 27.3, Avg: 27.4, Max: 27.5, Diff: 0.2, Sum: 109.6]
      [GC Worker End (ms): Min: 39329299.3, Avg: 39329299.3, Max: 39329299.3, Diff: 0.0]
   [Code Root Fixup: 0.1 ms]
   [Code Root Purge: 0.0 ms]
   [Clear CT: 0.3 ms]
   [Other: 2.9 ms]
      [Choose CSet: 0.1 ms]
      [Ref Proc: 0.4 ms]
      [Ref Enq: 0.0 ms]
      [Redirty Cards: 0.1 ms]
      [Humongous Reclaim: 0.0 ms]
      [Free CSet: 1.3 ms]
   [Eden: 288.0M(288.0M)->0.0B(284.0M) Survivors: 6144.0K->10.0M Heap: 403.6M(492.0M)->119.6M(492.0M)]
 [Times: user=0.08 sys=0.01, real=0.03 secs] 
2019-01-29T22:27:04.257+0000: [GC pause (G1 Evacuation Pause) (young)
Desired survivor size 19922944 bytes, new threshold 15 (max 15)
- age   1:    6478080 bytes,    6478080 total
- age   2:      39296 bytes,    6517376 total
 39356.002: [G1Ergonomics (CSet Construction) start choosing CSet, _pending_cards: 1055, predicted base time: 13.21 ms, remaining time: 186.79 ms, target pause time: 200.00 ms]
 39356.026: [G1Ergonomics (CSet Construction) add young regions to CSet, eden: 142 regions, survivors: 5 regions, predicted young region time: 78.96 ms]
 39356.026: [G1Ergonomics (CSet Construction) finish choosing CSet, eden: 142 regions, survivors: 5 regions, old: 0 regions, predicted pause time: 92.17 ms, target pause time: 200.00 ms]
, 1.8688598 secs]
   [Parallel Time: 1017.6 ms, GC Workers: 4]
      [GC Worker Start (ms): Min: 39356160.3, Avg: 39356164.6, Max: 39356169.7, Diff: 9.4]
      [Ext Root Scanning (ms): Min: 247.7, Avg: 329.1, Max: 491.2, Diff: 243.5, Sum: 1316.5]
      [Update RS (ms): Min: 0.1, Avg: 183.7, Max: 426.5, Diff: 426.4, Sum: 734.8]
         [Processed Buffers: Min: 1, Avg: 10.2, Max: 35, Diff: 34, Sum: 41]
      [Scan RS (ms): Min: 0.0, Avg: 0.1, Max: 0.2, Diff: 0.2, Sum: 0.3]
      [Code Root Scanning (ms): Min: 0.0, Avg: 0.0, Max: 0.0, Diff: 0.0, Sum: 0.0]
      [Object Copy (ms): Min: 261.0, Avg: 425.0, Max: 500.8, Diff: 239.9, Sum: 1700.2]
      [Termination (ms): Min: 0.0, Avg: 29.0, Max: 43.5, Diff: 43.5, Sum: 116.0]
      [GC Worker Other (ms): Min: 2.0, Avg: 30.6, Max: 54.2, Diff: 52.2, Sum: 122.3]
      [GC Worker Total (ms): Min: 994.4, Avg: 997.5, Max: 1001.3, Diff: 6.9, Sum: 3990.1]
      [GC Worker End (ms): Min: 39357154.7, Avg: 39357162.1, Max: 39357168.5, Diff: 13.8]
   [Code Root Fixup: 0.6 ms]
   [Code Root Purge: 0.0 ms]
   [Clear CT: 200.2 ms]
   [Other: 650.5 ms]
      [Choose CSet: 23.8 ms]
      [Ref Proc: 0.7 ms]
      [Ref Enq: 0.0 ms]
      [Redirty Cards: 0.2 ms]
      [Humongous Reclaim: 0.0 ms]
      [Free CSet: 473.1 ms]
   [Eden: 284.0M(284.0M)->0.0B(2048.0K) Survivors: 10.0M->24.0M Heap: 403.6M(492.0M)->134.6M(492.0M)]
 [Times: user=1.42 sys=0.12, real=1.87 secs]
```

Comment: That is indeed curious. The impact seems to be both on object copy and card tables. Does your application behavior change dramatically (e.g. from allocating large arrays to graphs of many small interconnected objects)? If not it would point to system performance itself changing (CPU throttling? VM quotas?)

Comment: Application behavior did not change. Yes it is very strange.